# Unable to read JSON message using Flask from Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, json, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I have a Python 'worker' using Elastic Beanstalk which reads messages from SQS. This works fine, although the scaling is clunky as it is based on cpu. Hence I'm trying to convert it to use AWS's new "Worker Tier Environment".

In at the deep end with Flask, but I have Flask running on an EB Work Tier. At the moment it is set to simply log the message information that it receives - this is to make sure I can read the information before I move everything else over. Unfortunately I cannot see any sign of the message?

Here is my Flask test code:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

from flask import Flask, request

logfile = "/opt/python/log/scan.log"
mylog = logging.getLogger('helloworld')
# (for brevity, log format/config code removed)

application = Flask(__name__)
app = application
app.Debug=True

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    global mylog
    err = "Unrecognized method"
    mylog.warning("Hello called")

    request_detail = """
# Before Request #
request.endpoint: {request.endpoint}
request.method: {request.method}
request.view_args: {request.view_args}
request.args: {request.args}
request.form: {request.form}
request.user_agent: {request.user_agent}
request.files: {request.files}
request.is_xhr: {request.is_xhr}
## request.headers ##
{request.headers}
    """.format(request=request).strip()
    mylog.warning(request_detail)

    mylog.warning("Moreinfo:")

    mylog.warning("Args:")
    for k in request.args.keys():
        mylog.warning(k + ": "+request.args[k])
    mylog.warning("Form:")
    for k in request.form.keys():
        mylog.warning(k + ": "+request.form[k])
    mylog.warning("Files:"+len(request.files))
    for k in request.files.keys():
        mylog.warning(k + ": "+request.files[k])

    try:
        myJSON = request.get_json(force=True)
        if myJSON is None:
            mylog.warning("JSON could not be forced")
        else:
            mylog.warning("MyJSON size: " + len(myJSON))
            mylog.warning( "MyJSON: {myJSON}".format(myJSON=myJSON))
        if request.json is None:
            mylog.warning("NO JSON")
    except Exception as e:
        mylog.warning("Exception: " + e)

    # the code below is executed if the request method
    # was GET or the credentials were invalid
    mylog.warning("failure 404")
    return 'Failure: '+err , 404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Yes that big long format statement was borrowed from a book :-)

Here is a typical log output for a message:

```
WARNING:2014-02-20 15:34:37,418: Hello called

WARNING:2014-02-20 15:34:37,419: 
# Before Request # 
request.endpoint: hello 
request.method: POST 
request.view_args: {} 
request.args: ImmutableMultiDict([])
request.form: ImmutableMultiDict([])
request.user_agent: aws-sqsd 
request.files: ImmutableMultiDict([])
request.is_xhr: False
## request.headers ## 
X-Aws-Sqsd-Msgid: 232eea42-5485-478c-a57f-4afddbf77ba9 
X-Aws-Sqsd-Receive-Count: 199 
X-Aws-Sqsd-Queue: #<AWS::SQS::Queue:0xb9255e90> 
Content-Length: 59 
User-Agent: aws-sqsd 
X-Aws-Sqsd-First-Received-At: 2014-02-20T13:55:34Z 
Host: localhost 
Content-Type: application/json

WARNING:2014-02-20 15:34:37,419: Moreinfo:

WARNING:2014-02-20 15:34:37,419: Args:

WARNING:2014-02-20 15:34:37,420: Form:
```

Note that none of the ImmutableMultiDict structures appear to have any keys.
Also, none of the JSON methods/properties are returning anything.

The Content-Length field does vary between log entries, so it does look like the information is there. But how do I read it?

My JSON messages are written to SQS using BOTO, eg:

```
  my_queue = conn.get_queue('my_queue_name')
  m = Message()
  m.set_body( json.dumps( my_structure ) )
  my_queue.write(m)
```

I also tried entering a raw JSON message by hand using the SQS web interface. This does not work either - I was speculating we might have a character encoding issue/

Comment: Yes, the multidicts being empty is correct behaviour. Your log output is incomplete however, everything after `Form:` is missing. Where is `Files:`, where is the JSON related output?

Comment: It would appear the len(request.files) was cuasing a problem. Removing that from the end of that particular log, produces the "files" line  - and this then marks the new end of the log for the message. Nothing from the exception. I wonder if files is causing an exception. Investigating further...

Comment: Most likely you are exhausting the body read in a way incompetable with the `.get_json()` call (which uses `request.get_data(cache=True)` if `request.get_data()` exists, otherwise `request.data`).

Comment: Martijn: I don't understand?   I've just commented the "Files" loop, and I'm not seeing anything in the logs from the json try..except clause. Which is weird!

Comment: Can you remove *all logging* before the `try:` call?

Comment: Sure - it is a quick turnaround here (I have SQS expiry times set very low).

Comment: And I get nothing! Empty log file. I commented out everything ahead of the try clause. And added a log warning just afterwards. Nothing is logged!

Comment: And nothing is returned either? No response is given? Next tack: use `try:`, `body = request.get_data(True)`, `except AttributeError:`, `body = request.data`, `mylog.warning('Request body: {!r}'.format(body))` and see what that logs. Remove all JSON handling (exception block included).

Comment: oooh - I'm seeing something!  Both my hand-typed JSON (as string), and the base64 encoded (BOTO-created) messages. I assume the latter are correct - I haven't tried decoding them yet. So I should have been using get_data all along? Helpful AWS docs again lol! Would you like to post it as an answer and I can then 'accept' it? Thanks again - I was losing hair over this lastnight...

Comment: No, not so fast; that was just to narrow down the problem here. That's how the `get_json()` method retrieves the request body before decoding; it appears that perhaps the `json` module is broken here. What happens when you replace the whole view with `from flask import json`, `data = json.loads('{"foo":"bar"}')`, `mylog.warning('JSON decoded to: {}'.format(data))`?

Comment: Yes looks to be working. The log entries mark "foo" and "bar" as unicode. One thought: my requirements.txt says flask 0.9 - from earlier problems, I went back from 0.10 to what the AWS documents explicitly referred to.

Comment: Here's another thought: Not knowing about get_data(), my original versions kept failing as Flask's json probably does not know about boto's base64 encoding. So I added all that log junk/etc which introduced its own problems. Then I added my native json message, and that didn't work because of all the log issues?

Comment: The log / junk you added didn't seem to be working; it looked as if there was an exception in there somewhere then. What is the Boto base64 encoding? Flask 0.9 or 0.10 won't make a difference here.

Comment: The boto Message class will encode the payload (json) as base 64. This is what I want as it can contain some unicode which messed things up (been there, got the t-shirt). So it sounds like I should use get_data, and then perform my own base64 & json decoding.

Comment: In that case use `request.data` as that is the documented API.

Comment: On second thought; stick to `get_data()`; the werkzeug source makes it clear that that is the better choice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not clear why your message logging is being cut off; perhaps you have an indentation error and part of your logging code is not considered part of the view method.

However, if I understand you correctly, Boto SQS messages are not only encoded as JSON, the JSON message itself is also [base64 encoded](https://code.google.com/p/boto/source/browse/trunk/boto/sqs/jsonmessage.py?r=1302), which would mean that the `flask.get_json()` method won't decode it for you.

Instead, use the [`request.get_data()` method](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.get_data) to access the raw POST data and do the decoding yourself; do first verify that the `request.content_length` value is within a tolerable size to prevent an attacker from sending you an overlarge message:

```
from flask import json
import base64

if request.mime_type == 'application/json' and request.content_length <= 1024**2:
    # message is JSON and smaller than 1 megabyte
    try:
        decoded = base64.b64decode(request.get_data())
        data = json.loads(decoded)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        mylog.exception('Failed to decode JSON')
    else:
        # do something with the decoded data
```

Comment: Following on from our comment discussion above, your sample code is almost exactly what I have implemented so far (I'm not explicitly checking the MIME type at the moment).  For the Worker thread I'll need to return a '200' for a bad message so that the poison message gets removed from the queue. I also suspect my try...except wasn't catching everything it should.

Comment: `json.loads()` throws `ValueError`, `base64.b64decode()` throws `TypeError` when passed incorrect data.

Comment: Wow - this answer is a real lifesaver.  Had no idea that base64 encoding was going on -.-